# Nginx error "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream" with generated file download

Tags: nginx, php, http-headers

I just spent the whole day trying to figure out this error.

We have a PHP script that generates a file for download. After upgrading nginx (1.16 -> 1.24), this script suddenly started randomly failing for some files.

The error in the nginx log was: "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream."

Nothing else was wrong; nothing else was logged. I did not find any relevant reports about this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out it was caused by a mismatch between the Content-Length header and the actual size of the generated file. We were sending a Content-Length header size that was 1 byte bigger than the actual size of the file. It seems that nginx, in these cases, randomly fails with the mentioned error message, waiting for the missing byte.

So, if you encounter this error, check if your Content-Length is correct.